# Timeline for careers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs

I love careers, it gave me the opportunity to put online a very polished CV, something everybody has to do every once in a while. I am currently employed, but academia is very unstable and unreliable, and despite the personal involvement in my current project I always keep my ears open for a good and challenging alternative, just in case I find myself out in the woods.

I was wondering what is the timeline for careers, when it's going out of beta, plan for advertising, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reminder -- I had been meaning to remove the "beta" part of the logo for a while now.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com has been fully functional for a while now.

Not that there aren't tweaks over time and new versions, of course, but it's functioning as originally intended in V1.